# flask-sqlalchemy как правильно фильтровать данные по множественным фильтрам

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

Как правильно фильтровать данные по запросу, где фильтры могут принимать множественные параметры (как в интернет-магазинах)?
Для примера: фильтровать помещения в здании, по этажу(ам) и допустим площади.
Где площадь "between". Я так понимаю делать тупо через if неправильно:

```
if request.form.get['key1']:
    query1
elif request.form.get['key2']:
    query2
elif:
else:
```

Пошлите, плз, в нужное направление.

Answer (score 0):

После долгих поисков нашёл, что можно сделать так:

```
query = db.session.query(Data).filter(Data.somefield == 'None') # Base query
if floorsFilter:
    query = query.filter(Data.floor.in_((floorsFilter)))
info = query.all()
```

Comment: `Data.floor.in_((floorsFilter))` - это то же самое что просто `Data.floor.in_(floorsFilter)`. Если нужно просто как параметр передать, то дополнительные скобки не нужны. Если предполагается tuple из одного элемента, то нужно добавить запятую во внутренних скобках: `(floorsFilter,)`